# Pandas move rows into single column and reshape dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the following dataframe that is ~1,400,000 rows:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B','D','D','F'], 'start1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'start2':[12,11,10,6,7], 'start3':[1,6,2,4,5], 'start4':[5,4,2,3,1], 'start5':[0,0,0,0,0], 'end1':[2,3,4,7,9] })


ID  start1  start2  start3  start4  start5   end1
A   1       12      1       5       0        2
B   2       11      6       4       0        3
D   3       10      2       2       0        4
D   4       6       4       3       0        7
F   5       7       5       1       0        9
```

I'm looking to collapse all rows that contain column headers 'start' or 'end' into the following format:

desired output:

```
ID    start     end
A     1         NaN
A     12        NAN
A     1         NAN
A     5         NaN
A     0         NaN
A     NaN       2
B     2         NaN
B     11        NaN
B     6         NaN
B     4         NaN
B     0         NaN
B     3         NaN
...
F     1         NaN
F     0         NaN
F     NaN       9
```

I have tried:

```
joined = df2.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(xi) for xi in x]), axis=1)
split = joined.str.split('', expand=True).reset_index(drop=False).melt(id_vars='index')
```

However this seems to use up all my memory and the environment crashes.
Any help would be great

Comment: Note that the 'ID' column is not the index but an actual column itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `melt` the `start` columns and `concat`

```
(pd.concat([x.iloc[:,:-1].melt('ID', value_name='start')
            .sort_values(['ID','variable']).drop('variable',axis=1),
           x[['ID','end1']]
          ])
      .sort_values('ID', kind='mergesort')
     )
```

Output:

```
   ID  start  end1
0   A    1.0   NaN
5   A   12.0   NaN
10  A    1.0   NaN
15  A    5.0   NaN
20  A    0.0   NaN
0   A    NaN   2.0
1   B    2.0   NaN
6   B   11.0   NaN
11  B    6.0   NaN
16  B    4.0   NaN
21  B    0.0   NaN
1   B    NaN   3.0
2   D    3.0   NaN
3   D    4.0   NaN
7   D   10.0   NaN
8   D    6.0   NaN
12  D    2.0   NaN
13  D    4.0   NaN
17  D    2.0   NaN
18  D    3.0   NaN
22  D    0.0   NaN
23  D    0.0   NaN
2   D    NaN   4.0
3   D    NaN   7.0
4   F    5.0   NaN
9   F    7.0   NaN
14  F    5.0   NaN
19  F    1.0   NaN
24  F    0.0   NaN
4   F    NaN   9.0
```

Remember that you are trying to duplicate a large amount of data here, so you need to be careful.

Comment: This doesn't match the expected output.  Last value of `start` is getting lost.

Comment: Sure. I counted the number of `ID = A` in yours and expected output. In your case it's 5 and in expected output it's 6.

Comment: Ah I see, I overlooked the data. Thanks for pointing out. Updated to match the output.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np

out = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ID', 'start', 'end'])
for col in x.columns: 
    if 'start'in col:
        out_col = 'start'
    if 'end' in col:
        out_col = 'end'
    if 'ID' not in col:
        temp = x[['ID', col]].rename(columns = {col:out_col})
        out = pd.concat([out,temp])
```

Output:

```
ID  start   end
0   A   1   NaN
0   A   0   NaN
0   A   NaN 2
0   A   12  NaN
0   A   5   NaN
0   A   1   NaN
1   B   0   NaN
1   B   4   NaN
1   B   NaN 3
1   B   6   NaN
1   B   11  NaN
1   B   2   NaN
2   D   10  NaN
2   D   0   NaN
2   D   2   NaN
3   D   4   NaN
3   D   NaN 7
2   D   NaN 4
2   D   2   NaN
3   D   3   NaN
3   D   4   NaN
2   D   3   NaN
3   D   6   NaN
3   D   0   NaN
4   F   5   NaN
4   F   1   NaN
4   F   7   NaN
4   F   5   NaN
4   F   0   NaN
4   F   NaN 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all columns into one by .ravel()

So: add **end1** and **Id** to another variable

```
end1values = x['end1']a
idvalues = x['ID']
```

Remove **end** and **Id** from data set:

```
x.drop('end1', 
  axis='columns', inplace=True)

x.drop('ID', 
  axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

use **Ravel** for starts:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start':x.values.ravel()})
```

Add end1 + ID

```
df['ID'] = idvalues
df['end'] = end1values
```

Result:
[image]